# Get associated row from history table

Tags: sql-server

If you have a table which holds history (updates, deletes) from another table, how would you pull an associated update row if it comes after a delete operation?

Table has the following columns not related to the data
ID int,      -- Identity
OP varchar   -- the delete or update operation coded as 'D' or 'U'
Removed_Date -- the date the row was removed from the 'Live' table

I've tried something like this
Select *
from historytable as table1
join historytable as table2 on table1.Removed_Date like table2.Removed_Date

which results in multiple rows (ten or more) of duplicates for one row in the table.

Comment: By "associated", do you mean that the user performed an update on the SAME record that was previously deleted?  Or, are you looking for the first update that is performed on ANY record after a record was deleted?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to identify merges, so say person A and person B are identified as the same individual (Maybe one record had a nickname). The application stores this as a delete and then an update.

Comment: Then, you need one or more fields in your history table that you can use to determine that this Delete operation and this Update operation were performed on records belonging to the same logical person.

Comment: Also, shouldn't that be a Delete and an Insert (how do you update a record that has been deleted)?

Comment: Well, it's not an application that I wrote.  I agree it seems poorly designed. As for the merge operation, the record for person A is deleted, while the record for person B is kept.

Comment: So then there is no definitive way to know what pair of Delete/Update history records were part of the same logical "merge" operation?

Comment: Yes. I wrote a quick perl script to get the data.  I guess there are some things one shouldn't try with SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing in Perl:

while (<>) {
        @cols = split(/,/);
        $removeby = $cols[3];
        if ($cols[1] eq "D" and $removeby!~/ottr|hksys/)  {
                if ($hold) {
                        @oldCols = split(/,/,$hold);
                        $oldRemoveBy = $oldCols[3];
                        if ($removeby eq $oldRemoveBy) {
                                print $hold;
                                print;
                        }
                        $hold = "";
                }
                $hold = "";
        } else {
                $hold = $_;
        }
}

It's not a fool-proof solution, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are absolutely sure the timestamps are identical for a delete and corresponding update you can do this:

```
select *
from historytable as table1
inner join historytable as table2 on table1.Removed_Date = table2.Removed_Date 
where table1.OP = 'D' 
and table2.op = 'U'
```

If the timestamps are not identical, and you have no other way of determining which UPDATE follows which DELETE, all you can do is retrieve the first UPDATE after a DELETE.

```
select t1.*, 
  (select top 1 id 
  from historytable t2 
  where t2.Removed_Date > t1.Removed_Date
  and t2.code = 'U')
from historytable t1 where code = 'D'
```

-Edoode

Comment: No, the timestampes are not identical.  Your second query looks interesting, but I ended up with rows where the top 1 value was duplicated.  Thanks Anyway!

Comment: If you can provide a couple of example rows of the historytable I might be able to help.